# Foreach on ImageListView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, thumbnails

I am trying to implement a foreach loop on a ListViewItem.

```
 foreach(ListViewItem eachItem in ThumbnailLists.SelectedItems)
 {
     // do something
 }
```

The problem is my `ThumbnailLists` is of type `Manina.Windows.Forms.ImageListViewItem` and it couldn't be converted to `System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem`. Therefore, I couldn't use the foreach on my thumbnail. Is there any way I could by pass this or fix this?

### Edit

I tried something like this:

```
 foreach (ImageListViewItem eachItem in ThumbnailLists.SelectedItems)
 {
     ThumbnailLists.Items.Remove(eachItem);
 }
```

However, it doesn't delete all the thumbnails, only leaving one left. It only works if there are less than 5 thumbnails.

Comment: I would suggest you rephrase the question since what you need didn't really fit what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
this.ThumbnailLists.Clear();
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to remove thumbnail on my program if I select all of them, then all will be deleted. Is this possible?

Comment: Okay. Can you take a look at my edited post? Maybe that will help explaining what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Daredevil click the grey tick at the left side to mark this reply as accepted answer if it solves your question.